# How can I strip tab characters from a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a program that loads some tab-separated lines into a MySQL table. One of the values has tabs in it, which is causing some problems. The data is created column by column, so I need to find a way to strip the tab character out of an individual field with gsub. I do not, however, want to get rid of anything else, like spaces.

Comment: Are you using Ruby's CSV module? CSV is a very convoluted almosta-spec, so it behooves you to take advantage of the library whenever possible, rather than try to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's really easy `\t` is the tab character.

```
result = string.gsub /\t/, ''
```

or, in-place

```
string.gsub! /\t/, ''
```

Comment: You should probably include an assignment in your sample code, or some usage that shows that this is a non-mutating method.

Answer (score 1):

`\t` is the escape character for tabs within strings. So you can just search for `"\t"` and replace that by a space or something.